# docker + golang lib/pq "dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused"

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, kubernetes, docker-compose

`sql.Open()` wouldn't error:

```golang
if db, err = sql.Open("postgres", url); err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Postgres connect error : (%v)", err)
}
```

but `db.Ping()` would error:

```golang
if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Postgres ping error : (%v)", err)
}
```

and it was simply because the lib/pq connection string wouldn't connect from within a docker container with the seperated connection parameters.

For example:

```golang
url := fmt.Sprintf("user=%v password=%v host=%v port=%v dbname=%v",
    rs.conf.Redshift.User,
    rs.conf.Redshift.Password,
    rs.conf.Redshift.Host,
    rs.conf.Redshift.Port,
    rs.conf.Redshift.DB)
```

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to close your question, and we aren't trying to say you are doing it wrong, but I am saying that what you have described isn't an effective debugging technique. Pop into [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust) if you want. Please flag this comment as "no longer needed" once you see it to keep this Q&A tidy.

Comment: @Shepmaster, I'm here now: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334761/stack-overflow-chat-asks-me-to-log-in-but-i-am-already-logged-in#comment729892_334761
my luck right now is 

Comment: weird. It looks like you have some weird vestigial account  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/244193/mikeumus

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the connection string as a URL worked:

```golang
    url := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%v:%v@%v:%v/%v?sslmode=disable",
        pql.conf.Postgres.User,
        pql.conf.Postgres.Password,
        pql.conf.Postgres.Host,
        pql.conf.Postgres.Port,
        pql.conf.Postgres.DB)
```

See lib/pq docs here:
https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq

I was stuck on this for more than a day and I owe the fix to Nikolay Sandalov's comment here in GitHub:
https://github.com/coreos/clair/issues/134#issuecomment-491300639

Thank you, Nikolay ‍♂️

Comment: Worked for me, plussed from 2 accounts=)

Comment: Worked like charm

Comment: For those who use docker, instead of HOST, use:

   host.docker.internal